# how to check strings array's 1st elements 1st symbol with if?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

So basically I got string array, lets say `a[i][b];`

so the code looks something like this -

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for(int n = 0; b < 3; b++) {
    if(a[i][b] == "s") {
     cout << a[i][b] << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

the array exists, and I can check it if I just show on console the `a[i][b]` without if statement, but with if statement it gives me this error -

> error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer

Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: don't you think it's important to know what `a` is? :/

Comment: where is n coming into this? can you give us all of the code?

Comment: Of what type is *a*? If it is a char**, you might want to check against a single character in your if condition, e.g. if(a[i][b]=='s')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"s" is a string literal, i.e. a character array, so decays to a pointer. To just compare to a character, use single quotes:

```
if (a[i][b]=='s')
```

Comment: That worked, lol thanks! Will accepted as soon as I will be able to!

Answer (score 3):

`"s"` is a C string literal, if you want to compare with a character use `'s'`.

Answer (score 1):

put `s` in single quotes like this `'s'`
`"s"` is a text and in C++ there is no String class (native). So `"s"` is actually a pointer to character sequence and `a[i][b]` is just a single character.